# How To get Language by Country in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, globalization

What's the best way to solve it?

I have tried :

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class HelloWorld {
    static void Main() {
        List<CultureInfo> CultureInfos = CultureInfo
                            .GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                            .ToList();

        var a = CultureInfos.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Contains("Israel"))
                            .FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine(a?.DisplayName.Split(' ')[0]);
    }
}
```

Funny thing, It works on onlinegdb.com but doesn't work on my local machine .Net core 3.1. It returns Null in "a"
Tried to find any clue to their .Net version - no success

Do you know why? / What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Use `ThreeLetterISOName` or `TwoLetterISOName` instead.  Any of the other name choices would be better than `DisplayName`.

Comment: I dont have the name of the country...its just for the example. I only have get Country name from API and need to fill the language my self @RobertHarvey

Comment: [`DisplayName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.displayname?view=netcore-3.1) is itself localized, depending on the environment. So doing a `Contains` on it could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Ok it seems like RegionInfo contains the plain country name.
Using `EnglishName`so you have a baseline. If you use `DisplayName` it depends on the CurrentCulture if your code works.

For example on a german system "Austria" would'nt work, but "Österreich"

```
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                             .FirstOrDefault(c => new RegionInfo(c.Name).EnglishName == "Israel"));
```

See working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VU0EAI).